# I'm trying to archive a meteor-built ios app, but Xcode but I keep getting 'Ambiguous use of […]'

Tags: ios, xcode, meteor-ios

I built this project from a meteor app (with meteor build ios...).

I've set it to use the legacy version of Swift (otherwise I get a lot of errors). But when I try to archive it, i get this error in different locations.

```
func cancel() { // Error: Ambiguous use of 'dispatch_sync(_:block)'
  dispatch_sync(queue) {
    self._cancel()
  }
}

func dispatch_sync(queue: dispatch_queue_t, block: () throws -> ())throws {  // 1. Found this candidate 
  var caughtError: ErrorType?

  dispatch_sync(queue) {
    do {
      try block()
    } catch {
      caughtError = error
    }
  }

  if let caughtError = caughtError {
      throw caughtError
    }
  }

  func cancel() { // 2. Found this candidate
    dispatch_sync(queue) {
      self._cancel()
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to solve it, could you help me?

PS: I'm using the latest version of Xcode with MacOS Sierra. And Meteor 1.4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Rename your function dispach_sync into, for instance, dispatch_sync_mine

Comment: thanks, but not success, i'm trying another way to archive app